# Is it possible to implement Newton's Dot Notation (or Lagrange's Prime Notation) in sympy?

Tags: python, physics, sympy

Leibniz's notation can just be a bit cluttering, especially in physics problems where time is the only variable that functions are being differentiated with respect to. Additionally, is it possible to not display the `(t)` for a function like `x(t)` with sympy still understanding that `x` is a function of `t` and treating it as such?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [mechanics module](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/physics/mechanics/index.html), which was designed around Newtonian physics.  In particular, `dynamicssymbols` will give you a symbol which implicitly depends on `t`.

```
In [10]: x, y = dynamicsymbols('x y')

In [11]: x
Out[11]: x(t)
```

By default, these will still print with the `(t)`, but if you enable the mechanics printers, they will not.

```
In [1]: from sympy.physics.mechanics import dynamicsymbols, init_vprinting

In [2]: init_vprinting
Out[2]: <function sympy.physics.vector.printing.init_vprinting>

In [3]: init_vprinting()

In [4]: x
Out[4]: x

In [5]: t = sympy.Symbol('t')

In [6]: y.diff(t)
Out[6]: ẏ
```

Use `init_vprinting` instead of `init_printing` in whatever interactive environment you develop in, such as the IPython notebook (there are also functions like `mpprint` if you want to print things from a scrpt).

If you want to know more about the SymPy mechanics module, read the documentation, and also take a look at the [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lWbeuDwYVto) from the 2014 SciPy conference.